# Is it possible to include just a specific div of a file?

Tags: php

Is it possible to include just a specific div of a file? Something like this:

```
<?php include ('store.php/footer');?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not using the `include` function.

You could read the file into a string with `fopen`, parse it with `DOMDocument` then extract the bit you want with DOM methods and then `echo` the result – but this wouldn't process any PHP in the file. You'd have to `eval` that (or similar) separately.

You'd almost certainly be better off restructuring your PHP so that the parts you want to use are in separate files to start with and then include them from multiple places.

Comment: ...or you could try to keep your sanity and practice proper code separation from the beginning... ;)

Comment: Thanks, let's say solved :). Especially thanks to YCS for his large explanation.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not. Not least of all because PHP does't care about HTML. If you need elements separately in different files, separate them out into different files or functions and include them where needed.